# d3.js can't change outer radius of arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some donut layout in my code:

```
    var cityPercentage=[50,30,20,10];
    var width=300,
        height=300,
        radius=100;
    var color=d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0,60])
                .range(["red","blue"]);
    var cityDivision = d3.select("#cities")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("class","span4");
    var group=cityDivision.append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
    var arc=d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius-19)
        .outerRadius(radius);
    var pie= d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function(d){return d;});
var arcs=group.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(cityPercentage))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class","arc")
    .attr("id",function(d){return d.data;});
    arcs.append("path")
    .attr("d",arc)
    .attr("fill",function(d){return color(d.data);});
```

on mouse over I want it to enlarge it's outerRadius.
Here is what I have:

```
    $(".arc").on("mouseover",(function(){
    console.log($(this).find("path"));
    $(this).find("path").transition()
    .duration(10)
    .attr("outerRadius",radius+20);
}));
```

It says

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function VM24:44
(anonymous function) VM24:44
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:5095
elemData.handle
```

Comment: You need to change the radius of the arc generator and then regenerate the path. See e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4341417).

Comment: made some edits now, this doesn't enlarge radius either.

Comment: Let me say that again: you need to change the radius of *the arc generator* and regenerate the path. You're currently changing an attribute of a `g` element that, as you observed, has no effect at all.

Comment: It finds path ok, but gives the mistake.

Comment: The **arc generator** -- the thing that is called `arc` in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should probably transition the arc using an arc generator.

Add an `onClick` listener and create another type of arc, and then simply transition the `d` attribute of the path:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius-19)
  .outerRadius(radius);

var arcLarge = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius-25)
  .outerRadius(radius + 10);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d){return d;});

var toggleArc = function(p){
    p.state = !p.state;
    var dest = p.state ? arcLarge : arc;

    d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("d", dest);
};

var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(cityPercentage))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class","arc")
  .attr("id",function(d){return d.data;})
  .on("click",toggleArc)
      .append("path")
  .attr("d",arc)
  .attr("fill",function(d){return color(d.data);});
```

in this example, I toggle the state of the data element, so it toggles between the normal and expanded form.

See [this CodePen example](http://codepen.io/MasterAM/pen/cipuL).

Comment: i think you need to remove ';' after 'on(click,toggleArc)'

Answer (score 1):

Using transition we can do  this

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 400)
.attr("height", 400)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");
 var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(20)
.outerRadius(20)
.startAngle(0)
.endAngle(Math.PI);
 svg.append("path")
.attr("id", "arc1")
.attr("d", arc);
 arc.outerRadius(70);
 d3.select("#arc1").transition()
.duration(1000)
.attr("d", arc);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renjithgovind/3p3k83mc/)